# Differential Riccati-type equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, matrix-analysis, linear-pde, matrix-equations

### Setup

I have recently come across an ODE of the form
$$
0 = \dot{A}(t)^TG(t) + A(t)^T\dot{G}(t) + C(t) + \lambda B(t)^TA(t)G(t) + \frac{\lambda}{2} (D(t)A(t)G(t))(D(t)A(t)G(t))^T\bar{1},
$$
where $\dot{A}(t)$ is the time derivative of $A(t)$, $A$ and $D$ are $\mathbb{R}$eal-Matrix-valued functions, $G, C$ and $B$ are vector-valued functions, $\lambda$ is a constant and $\bar{1}$ is the vector with only $1$s as entries.

### Question

My question is: when is there a solution to this equation and what is it explicitly?

### What I've been thinking

I've looked up nonsymmetric Riccati equations but I'm not certain this falls into that class of equations or if it is even solvable.

Comment: What is known/unknown? Also, the last term in the differential equation looks like a vector (not a matrix), since $\bar{1}$ is a vector? Are all of the known matrices invertible uniformly in $t$?

Comment: Hey, by unknown I don't mean random but just what I'm solving for and yes in this particular problem all matrices are invertible for all values of $t$.

Comment: Yes, but what is the unknown matrix-valued function in your DE, i.e., the matrix-valued function you're trying to solve for.  Is it $A(t)$ or $G(t)$?

Comment: I'm trying to solve for $A(t)$.

Comment: You do not give any assumptions on your data $G,B,C,D$ (which is really a no-no) and your equation is in implicit form in $\dot A$. This leaves too many options for a reasonable answer. If $G(t)$ is invertible it is really a differential equation, because we can multiply by $G(t)^{-1}$ to get the $\dot A$. If not you have an differential-algebraic equation. Still things can be said. But without knowing what you want it is hard to answer.

Comment: I added some details but no G is vector valued and $A$ is matricial.

Comment: Ricatti eq is often related to $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$

Comment: I am confused about the dimensions. If $A$ is matrix-valued (square $n\times n$ I suppose?), and B and G are vector-valued ($n\times 1$ I suppose?), how can you sum the vector $\dot A G$ and the scalar $\lambda B^T A G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any relation to matrix Riccati equations here, so may guess is that the literature on nonsymmetric Riccati equations will not help. Anyway, here is an approach to solving the system.

If we simply assume that $A$ is symmetric, the equation is not one for $A$, but rather one for $z(t):=A(t)G(t)= A(t)^TG(t)$. If we use this notation then the differential equation is
$$\dot{z}(t) = -C(t) - \lambda B(t) z(t) - \frac{\lambda}{2} (D(t)z(t))(D(t)z(t))^T\mathbf{1}.$$
This is a quadratic equation in $z$, so locally Lipschitz in $z$. So unique solutions to an inital value problem $z(t_0) = z_0$ will exist locally, if you assume $B,C,D$ are continuous (or if you want to appeal to Caratheodory's theorem, locally $L^1$ in $t$ will be fine). Because of the quadratic part forward completeness will be a problem of course and depend on data and initial conditions. For instance $\dot z = - z^2$ with $z\in\mathbb{R}$ is an example that fits in the class.

Now if $G$ is also part of your data, and you are looking for $A$, then you can pick a symmetric matrix-valued function $A(t)$ such that
$$ z(t;t_0,z_0) = A(t)G(t)$$
for all $t$ where $z(t;t_0,z_0)$ is defined. If $G(t)\neq 0$ always, then this can always be done. If $G(t)$ has zeros, you run into problems. Then it would depend on what $z$ happens to be doing at a zero of $G$.

Unfortunately, even if $G$ has no zeros, there are many symmetric matrix valued functions which solve the equation. So the problem seems to be, not whether a solution exists, but that you have way too many solutions. (Depending on what you want of course, maybe it is OK to assume that all entries of $G$ have no zeros and to insist on diagonal solutions for $A$).

Comment: If I assume G is invertible would this guarantee that there is a unique solution, without A having to be diagonal?

Comment: @CSA: You said $G$ is a vector. Then it makes no sense to speak of invertibility. It makes sense that $G$ should be a vector because the last term in the equation is a vector by construction..